# Sorted rotated integer array, search algorithm

Tags: arrays, algorithm, search, data-structures

An integer sorted array rotated to left by unknown no of times, write an efficient algorithm to search for an element.

Example: 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4

I am thinking every time I find a mid in Binary Search I compare the element with extreme end element and take a decision on which half to pick to repeat the process. Is it wrong? Or is there any efficient algo?

Answer (score 0):

Your example array contains duplicates. When there are duplicates there is no efficient algorithm - you must always do O(n) work in the worst case.

To prove this, consider arrays of this form:

```
000000000000000010000000
```

It is a rotation of a sorted array, but in the worst cast you must iterate over every element to see where the `1` is.